# Problema com âncoras no Safari em Windows

Tags: html, windows, safari

Olá, tenho duas páginas, uma delas contém uma âncora para uma seção da outra página:

```
<dsp:a page="${publicUrl}${URLs.club}#ancora" class="veja-mais block">
```

Nessa outra eu tenho uma , que está no devido lugar onde deve ser direcionada.

O problema que estou enfrentando é que quando eu clico no link que contém a âncora, o Safari remove o #, assim não direcionando.

Tentei usar uma section, name, class, mas mesmo assim não funciona.

Alguém sabe o que pode ser? Nos demais navegadores funciona corretamente.

Aqui os códigos:

Página 1: `<dsp:a page="${publicUrl}${URLs.club}#ancora" class="veja-mais block">`

Página 2: `<div id="ancora"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Esse é um problema conhecido do Safari. O browser remove as âncoras em casos de redirecionamentos para páginas diferentes (mais especificamente, quando redirect headers estão presentes).

Remover o redirecionamento não parece uma opção no seu caso, então sugiro que você tente substituir:

```
<dsp:a page="${publicUrl}${URLs.club}#ancora" class="veja-mais block">
```

por

```
<dsp:a page="${publicUrl}${URLs.club}/#ancora" class="veja-mais block">
```

A barra não interfere no funcionamento de outros browsers, e aparentemente soluciona o problema no Safari.

Fonte: [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020456/safari-anchors-on-links-not-working)

Comment: Tentei colocar a /#, porém nenhum navegador encontrou, deu 404 nas páginas.

Comment: Quais são os valores de ${publicUrl} e ${URLs.club}?

Comment: ${publicUrl} é a url principal do site 'www.site.com.br' e ${URLs.club} é a página '/club'.